# one-to-many unidirectional mapping with compound

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'm struggling with the following scenario:

I have 2 Tables:

```
RESULTS (
`L_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`PRIZE` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`SECONDARY_PRIZE` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`L_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |


STATISTICS (
`L_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`F_TYPE` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`RANK` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
`WINNERS` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`PRIZE` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`L_ID`,`F_TYPE`,`RANK`),
KEY `L_ID_FK_idx` (`L_ID`),
CONSTRAINT `L_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`L_ID`) REFERENCES `RESULTS` (`L_ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE  NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

And the following classes:

```
@Embeddable
public class StatisticId implements Serializable {

  @Column(name = "L_ID", unique=false, nullable=false, updatable=true, insertable=true)
  private long lId;

  @Column(name = "F_TYPE", unique=false, nullable=false, updatable=true, insertable=true)
  private int fType;

  @Column(name = "RANK_ID", unique = false, nullable = false, updatable = true, insertable = true, length = 2)
  private String rankId;

   ..Getters\Setters...
}
```

Statistic class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STATISTICS", uniqueConstraints = {})
public class Statistic implements Serializable {

  @EmbeddedId   
  @AttributeOverrides({ 
    @AttributeOverride(name = "lId", column = @Column(name = "L_ID", unique = false, nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)),
    @AttributeOverride(name = "fType", column = @Column(name = "F_TYPE", unique = false, nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)),
    @AttributeOverride(name = "rankId", column = @Column(name = "RANK_ID", unique = false, nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 2))
  })
  private StatisticId id;


  @Column(name = "WINNERS", unique = false, nullable = false, updatable = true, insertable = true)
  private long winners;

  @Column(name = "PRIZE", unique = false, nullable = false, updatable = true, insertable = true)
  private long prize;
}
```

and finally the RESULT TABLE:

```
@Entity
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
@Table(name = "RESULTS")
public class Result extends Form {

@Id
@Column(name = "L_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)    
    private long lId;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name="StatisticsResults",
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name="id.lId") }, 
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name="lId") }
)
private List<Statistic> statistics;

@Column(name = "PRIZE", unique = false, nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)
private long prize;

@Column(name = "SECONDARY_PRIZE", unique = false, nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true)
private long secondaryPrize;

}
```

I use Hibernate4.3beta with it's proxool pool connection.

The exception I get is:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: A Foreign key refering    
com.btl.server.database.beans.Statistic from com.btl.server.database.beans.Result has the wrong  
number of column. should be 2
```

What am I doing wring??

Thank you for your patience reading this!!

Answer (score 0):

Solved!!

The problem was HIbernate4.3 beta version, once I switched to 4.2.1Final it worked like a magic!!